# Software framework for internet-wide peer-to-peer applications

Tags: frameworks, distributed, p2p

Is there any known effort to build a generic software framework/library for building distributed/P2P systems on the wider internet[1]? Something that ideally should provide basic services such as peer autodiscovery, autoconfiguration (wrt NAT/firewall issues, bootstrapping), fault-tolerance (churn-resistance, adaptivity, replication), differentiated transports (reliable, unreliable, unicast, anycast, multicast, broadcast), basic storage (DHT-like) and events notification (pubsub).

So, basically something like Hazelcast but not limited to walled-garden server-to-server applications. This would be tremendously useful to easily build distributed applications.

[1] with "wider internet" I mean the public internet, including mobile, residential, eventually connected and possibly byzantine endpoints

Answer (score 0):

you will find different option and technologies depending on the framework you want to use.

For instance for Java based applications you might want to have a look at the [JXTA](http://www.win.tue.nl/~ymazuryk/books/m_jxta.pdf) technology.

Comment: what c++ based application.Is there any framework for c++ for p2p